# Hive query using string function

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am in need of manipulating a string based on its length. I have tried the below but getting an exception.

The requirement is like this.

I have a string in a column numbers as 123456 the result should be 12-34-56. If it is 1234 then 12-34-00. If only 2 digits then 12-00-00.

```
IF(LENGTH(numbers) = 2,concat(numbers,'-00-00') OR LENGTH(numbers) = 4,concat(SUBSTR(numbers,1,2),'-',SUBSTR(numbers,3,2),'-00') OR LENGTH(numbers) = 6,concat(SUBSTR(numbers,1,2),'-',SUBSTR(numbers,3,2),SUBSTR(msg.numbers,5,2))) as finalnumbers
```

The exception is :

```
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector
```

Any help ?

Comment: You could use the rpad function to pad out zeros to length 6.  That avoids using conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using CASE and WHEN at Hive queries. This forum gives explains precisely [conditional functions](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/conditional-functions-in-hive.html)

```
CASE 
WHEN (LENGTH(numbers) = "6") THEN concat(substring(numbers,1,2),'-',substring(numbers,3,2),'-',substring(numbers,5,2)) 
WHEN (LENGTH(numbers) = "4") THEN concat(substring(numbers,1,2),'-',substring(numbers,3,2),'-00')
WHEN (LENGTH(numbers) = "2") THEN concat(numbers,'-00-00') as finalnumbers
```